# Comparing two sets with "in" in Python

Tags: python, set, boolean, boolean-logic

I have two sets.

```
bestStudents = [56, 75, 23]
scholarships=[75, 23, 56]
```

I am trying to see if the elements in bestStudents are in the set scholarship, which they are.
When I use:
`(set(bestStudents) in set(scholarships))`
I get false

Why is that? All the elements of bestStudents are in scholarships?

Comment: did you mean to do `set(bestStudents) == set(scholarships)`

Comment: No. In this case they are equal length but not always.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`in` is not intended to compare `sets`:

```
>>> [23] in set(scholarships)
True

>>> {23} in set(scholarships)
False
```

You have some predicates to do that like `issubset`

```
>>> set(bestStudents).issubset(scholarships)
True
```

Comment: Correct answer of course. I think it might be worth showing `set(bestStudents) in [set(scholarships)]` to illustrate why OP was thinking about it the wrong way.

Comment: I think a shorthand is ```bestStudents < scholarships``` ?

Comment: You are totally right, maybe `<=`. Check https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.issubset